# Mucked cards when missed player

Tags: texas-hold-em

Player 1 bets, player 2 is skipped, player 3 folds.  Player 1 assumes win and puts cards face down. Player 2 realizes miss and calls. Player 1retrieves cards has best hand; who wins?

Comment: what is going on with player 2. why was he skipped was he away fom the tablw did the dealer miss him details sir please

Answer (score 1):

In any hand, the pot is awarded to the last player who still has live cards.  All other players will have either folded (in a non-showdown scenario) or have their hand mucked by the dealer or themselves (at showdown).

Answer (score 0):

this is one for a floorperson to decide. I am wondering what happened with player 2 and would have some questions about where he was why he was missed did he tell someone to kill his hand otherwise Mr. chins answer is fine enough. not enough data in the original op's question for a good concise answer.